# Badges not notes on the user profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "next badge" dialog correctly displays bronze and silver badge progress with notes instead of dots to decorate the badge titles. But the current badge counts still use the dots.

Hopefully that makes sense.

In a related bug, I don't see any badge decoration on the gold badges in the "next badge" dialog (should be a whole note, I believe).

Exhibit A: Dots, not notes.

[image: Badges are still dots]

Exhibit B: Notes, not dots. Gold ones missing. Silver and bronze a bit hard to see, IMO.
[image: Select next badge]

Comment: In your first image, with the silver dot next to the "4" and the bronze dot next to the "28", I see the same thing on Math.SE and they have custom badge symbols and their design has been done for years, so that might be a Stack Exchange limitation that those dots can't be customized. **Below** that under "Newest" and "Next Badge", those **are** customized on Math.SE. And there should be gold badge icons on the badge progress screen.

Comment: Ah. I'm not on any other sites with custom designs so I hadn't considered that those could be status-by-design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exhibit A:** These dots are the same across the network. Sorry. At this time we haven't made these customizable yet.

**Exhibit B:** Good catch. Gold badges displayed correctly on the main site, but not on the meta site. There was an error in the sprite file. This has been corrected and will be fixed in the next production build.